# Alien appears on late-night talk show

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

This short story is from 40 or more years ago. I thought it was hilarious.

A late-night tv host has booked an alien on his show - the first public appearance of the being.

The host is a jerk who pokes fun at the alien, who is bemused by the host's actions.

Finally, the alien realizes the interview is supposed to be humorous, and immediately becomes a wise-cracking comedian, making the host look bad.

The alien becomes the show's new host.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_to_Ned

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This must surely be *[The Last Jerry Fagin Show](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64072)* by John Morressy, a short story first published in *Omni* in 1980.

Jerry Fagin is a comedian, who has the most successful chat show on Earth. One day he lands the tremendous coup of interviewing an alien, named Twelve, live on television. At first the interview is a disaster as the alien makes plodding, serious answers to Fagin's questions. Then Fagin starts to mercilessly mock Twelve, sending the audience into hysterics.

Finally the alien realises what is happening:

> "In my ignorance I assumed that this was to be a hoeimeius encounter.
> I employed my fourth voice. Had I known that it was to be a
> tonei-meiox I would have spoken thirdishly. Please forgive me Mr Jerry
> Fagin."

The alien's whole demeanour changes and he starts telling jokes. He has been observing Earth for decades, watching television, and so has a huge store of comedy routines from "Berle, Gleason, Caesar, Carson, Groucho, all of them". He completely wipes the floor with Fagin, and takes over Fagin's show which is renamed *Twelve at Twelve* (although it is still actually broadcast at 11:30).

The complete story is available from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/sim_omni_1980-04_2_7/page/58/mode/2up).

Comment: It is told from the viewpoint of a staff writer who had just been fired by Jerry Fagin, and who is subsequently hired by Twelve for his show. There is lots of oblique commentary on contemporaneous media culture. "Wink my wox!"

Comment: I guess Jerry Fagin is Jewish, like Jerry Seinfeld. Curiously, there has never been a Jewish *Tonight Show* host.